# Blender Geometry Nodes - Make One Line out of Multiple Extruded Edges

Tags: geometry-nodes

One line (indicated by the green hand-drawn line) is desired to be made from multiple edges extruded from a resampled curve with the rest of the geometry deleted:

[image: node network and resulting geometry]

The purpose for this setup is to be able to add a Fillet Curve node and bevel all of the vertices, netting a result similar to what the shortest path could achieve, but without the need for extra mesh data:

[image: with Fillet Curve node]

Ideally, the solution would be axis-independent to be compatible with n-gon / off-axis (XY) geometry:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you go for the block-step wave directly, rather than by using extrusions?

If you take a subdivided zigzag mesh line, scale even-index edges to 0 in X, and odd-index edges to 0 in Y..

[image]

.. then you have a stepped line of one sort or another, depending on the 'Steps' and the mapping in the *Map Range* node...

[image]

... which is directly available for: conversion to curve, filleting / merging,  to desired characteristics?

[image]

Here's a version that uses the same method for an arbitrary poly-line in XY, simulating your illustration as closely as possible. The only difference is that vertical edges need to be scaled to 0 in both X and Y:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Creating a block-step wave directly is a great, efficient solution, however (forgive my omission of this point in the question) it probably won't work on off-axis/n-gon splines, hence the first idea of an axis-independent block-step.

Comment: @bobhasajetpack always flat to the ground (XY)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @bobhasajetpack there you go... see edit.